# SFTP authentication with credentials in Wordpress MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, ssh, authentication, wordpress, sftp

I'm trying to find a solution that will allow for a user to connect to a server via SFTP using a provided username/key combination (stored in a Wordpress installation's MySQL database), without needing to constantly keep two or more separate systems in sync.

I asked this question on Stackoverflow, but I feel that it would be better answered here.

This is the MySQL query that gets two columns that have the username of a user and the api key, which the user would type in to their SFTP client as their password:

```
SELECT m.meta_value, u.user_login
FROM wp_users AS u, wp_usermeta AS m
WHERE m.user_id = u.ID AND m.meta_key = "user_apikey";
```

As far as the file system goes, there is a folder which has the same name as a user's username for each user, all in the same directory. This user's folder may or may not already exist. When a user makes an SFTP connection to the server, they should be shown only the contents of that folder once authenticated.

Hopefully someone knows of a simple solution to this problem. The only limitation I have is that this must run on a CentOS box, but I'm pretty open to any tools and languages.

Comment: I know proftpd can use mysql as a source for authentication.  It also has a sftp plugin.

Comment: just for future reference, there are instructions for using [proftpd authentication using mysql](http://www.khoosys.net/single.htm?ipg=848)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace the backends of PAM and the Name Service Switch (NSS) with a MySQL backend. You will need [pam-mysql](http://pam-mysql.sourceforge.net/) and [libnss-mysql](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/nss-mysql).

Might be overkill just to get one app to use MySQL, but figured I should mention it.